# How to detect if edit text is scrollable

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollbar

I have an edit text in which I need to check if it is scrollable (it has scrollbars=true) to change one of its features. I am not sure how to be able to tell when the scrollbar has been enabled. Since the scrollbar is horizontal, counting the lines is not an option. What options are there to check this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use custom EditText and overriding:

`onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt)`

which is inherited from TextView.